# create dictionary occurrences for each letter c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

We have a program that shows you how many times a letter is repeated in a text

```
string txt = input.text.ToLower();
        txt = Regex.Replace(txt, @"\s+", "").Replace(")","").Replace("(","").Replace(".","").Replace(",","").Replace("!","").Replace("?","") ;
        var letterCount = txt.Where(char.IsLetter).GroupBy(c => c).Select(v => new { Letter = v.Key, count = v.Count() });

        foreach (var c in letterCount)
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("Caracterul:{0} apare {1} ori", c.Letter.ToString(), c.count));
        }
```

And how do I give for the most repeating letter the value of 26, then for the one that repeats the less it gets 25 and for the one that only once a value in alphabetical order?
For example, the text "we are all happy"
Letter A is repeated three times and has the value of 26
For letter L 25
For P 24 and others in alphabetical order

And, finally, get their sum?
Sorry for my English!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this LINQ approach:

```
string input = "we are all happy";
var allCharValues = input.ToLookup(c => c)
    .Where(g => g.Key != ' ') // or you want spaces?
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .ThenBy(g => g.Key)  // you mentioned alphabetical ordering if two have same count
    .Select((x, index) => new { Char = x.Key, Value = 26 - index, Count = x.Count() });
foreach (var x in allCharValues)
    Console.WriteLine($"Char:{x.Char} Value:{x.Value} Count:{x.Count}");

int sum = allCharValues.Select(x => x.Value).Sum();
```

Comment: Okay, but if I enter "AAA" then the amount must be 26 + 26 + 26
In your case to the "AAA" text he puts the amount only 26 and not 78

Comment: @George: you haven't explained that in your question ;)

Comment: I understand this is a little more complicated?

Comment: And another question
 txt = Regex.Replace(txt, @"\s+", "").Replace(")","").Replace("(","").Replace(".","").Replace(",","").Replace("!","").Replace("?","");

Comment: Can this syntax be written differently or just like that?

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your question about removing unwanted characters:

I think you'd be better of just keeping all characters between `a` and `z`. You could write an extension method to do this, and convert to lowercase at the same time:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string AlphabeticChars(this string self)
    {
        var alphabeticChars = self.Select(char.ToLower).Where(c => 'a' <= c && c <= 'z');
        return new string(alphabeticChars.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Then you can use an approach as follows. This is similar to Tim's approach, but this uses `GroupBy()` to count the occurrences; it also uses the new Tuple syntax from C#7 to simplify things. Note that this ALSO names the tuple properties, so they are not using the default `Item1` and `Item2`.

```
string txt = "we, (are?) all! happy.";

var r = txt
    .AlphabeticChars()
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .Select(g => (Count: g.Count(), Char: g.Key))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Char)
    .Select((v, i) => (Occurance: v, Index: 26-i));

int sum = r.Sum(c => c.Occurance.Count * c.Index);

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```